# Displaying table with different fields depending on clicked textbox in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two `Textboxes` with some calculated values. `Table` is initially hided. When I click `TextBox1` I want to display fields `Field1, Field2, Field3` in Table, when I click `TextBox2` I want to display `fields Field4, Field5, Field6` in Table. Is it possible to do so?

I've tried to make visible table by "Display can be toggled by this report item" checkbox in Tablix properties and putting there one of the textboxes, but that wouldn't work for second Textbox to display different fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the **Visibility** of a row so you can have one row with your first set of data and then an additional row below.

I would use a **Parameter** to hold the value of what to show and then set the visibility for the row based on the parameter value.

```
=IIF(Parameters!TABLE.Value = "Table A", TRUE, FALSE)
```

The other row would be the opposite.

**OR**

You could add 3 **calculated fields** to the **Dataset** to switch the values based on the parameter.

```
=IIF(Parameters!TABLE.Value = "Table A", Fields!Field1.Value, Fields!Field4.Value)
```

Then your report would just reference the calculated fields.

With either method, you can set an **Action** on TextBox1 to **Go To Report** to open the same report but with the changed parameter value.